# Shuffling Answer Options Based on a Previous Questin in FocusVision's Decipher when there is an extra answer

Tags: rows, shuffle

Let's say I'm writing a survey in FocusVision's Decipher. Let's say I have a checkbox question with 4 answer options. I want the next question to be a radio question that has as answer options only those chosen in the previous question, and in the same shuffle order.

So naturally, I'll do this:

```
<radio label="Q2" shuffle="rows" shuffleBy="Q1" rowCond="Q1[row]">
some more code
</radio>
```

However, I also want something more. I want this Q2 question to have an additional "None of the above" answer option, which stays anchored at the bottom of the answer list. Naturally, the browser throws an error when loading the survey: "The number of rows on the shuffledBy question is different"

What can I do?

P.S. To clarify, I would NOT like to resort to including the "None of the above" option in Question 1 with the cond="0" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this between Q1 and Q2:

```
<exec>
q2.rows.order = q1.rows.order
</exec>
```

Then remove shuffleBy="Q1" from Q2.

Add the "None of the above" option with cond="1" in Q2 and that is it.